# Proxying a c# HttpWebRequest with nodejs

Tags: c#, node.js, proxy, httpwebrequest, http-proxy-middleware

I'm using `nodejs http-proxy-middleware` to forward requests.

```
const my_proxy = httpProxy({
    target: http://my-service:80,
    changeOrigin: true,
    onProxyReq: (proxyReq, req, res) => {
         proxyReq.setHeader('auth-source', my_auth_source)
    })
})
```

For request comming from other nodejs Express application, everything is fine.

My client asked for a c# application; so I'm using `c# HttpWebRequest` with `RequestStream.write()` to send request to my proxy.

However, my httpProxy throw a `Headers already set` error.

If I remove the `RequestStream.write()` part, and send a request without body, everything is fine as well.

What am I missing. Do I need to enable an option to authorize my request to be forwarded ?

Thank you